# Viewpager2 bad scrolling behavior in RTL

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I am using Viewpager2 in android, When I change the layout to RTL locale then it scrolls in reverse direction. but during setting up or initiating from right side, it couldn't scroll completely and stuck in between

I set the currentItem to 1 and then 0 to overcome this, but need a good solution